# Implementation of a custom zip iterator that works with std::ranges::transform as well as std:::transform

Tags: c++, iterator, std, std-ranges

I have implemented a zip iterator, and it works well when used with algorithm functions like `std::for_each` or `std::transform`. However, when I use it with `std::ranges::for_each` or `std::ranges::transform`, I encounter errors. What could be the reason?

Compile error:

```
 main.cpp:130:26: error: no match for call to ‘(const std::ranges::__for_each_fn) (zip >, std::vector, std::allocator >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > >, std::vector > >::iterator, zip >, std::vector, std::allocator >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > >, std::vector > >::iterator, main()::&)>)’
  130 |     std::ranges::for_each(zipped.begin(), zipped.end(), [](const auto& val) {
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  131 |         auto [x, y, z] = val;
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  132 |         cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << endl;
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  133 |     });
      |     ~~                    
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/algorithm:64,
                 from main.cpp:15:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/ranges_algo.h:184:7: note: candidate: ‘template  requires (input_iterator<_Iter>) && (sentinel_for<_Sent, _Iter>) && (indirectly_unary_invocable<_Fun, std::projected<_Iter, _Proj> >) constexpr std::ranges::for_each_result<_Iter, _Fun> std::ranges::__for_each_fn::operator()(_Iter, _Sent, _Fun, _Proj) const’
  184 |       operator()(_Iter __first, _Sent __last, _Fun __f, _Proj __proj = {}) const
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/ranges_algo.h:184:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/ranges_algo.h:184:7: note: constraints not satisfied
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:71,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_algobase.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/iterator_concepts.h: In substitution of ‘template<class _Iter, class _Sent, class _Proj, class _Fun>  requires (input_iterator<_Iter>) && (sentinel_for<_Sent, _Iter>) && (indirectly_unary_invocable<_Fun, std::projected<_Iter, _Proj> >) constexpr std::ranges::for_each_result<_Iter, _Fun> std::ranges::__for_each_fn::operator()(_Iter, _Sent, _Fun, _Proj) const [with _Iter = zip<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >::iterator; _Sent = zip<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >::iterator; _Proj = std::identity; _Fun = main()::<lambda(const auto:18&)>]’:
main.cpp:135:26:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/iterator_concepts.h:597:13:   required for the satisfaction of ‘weakly_incrementable<_Iter>’ [with _Iter = zip<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >::iterator]
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/iterator_concepts.h:611:13:   required for the satisfaction of ‘input_or_output_iterator<_Iter>’ [with _Iter = zip<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >::iterator]
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/iterator_concepts.h:633:13:   required for the satisfaction of ‘input_iterator<_Iter>’ [with _Iter = zip<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >::iterator]
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/iterator_concepts.h:598:10:   in requirements with ‘_Iter __i’ [with _Iter = zip<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >::iterator]
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/iterator_concepts.h:601:18: note: nested requirement ‘__is_signed_integer_like::type, std::incrementable_traits::type> >::type::difference_type>’ is not satisfied
  601 |         requires __detail::__is_signed_integer_like<iter_difference_t<_Iter>>;
      |         ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/iterator_concepts.h:603:12: note: the required expression ‘(__i ++)’ is invalid
  603 |         __i++;
      |         ~~~^~
cc1plus: note: set ‘-fconcepts-diagnostics-depth=’ to at least 2 for more detail
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/algorithm:64,
                 from main.cpp:15:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/ranges_algo.h:195:7: note: candidate: ‘template  requires (input_range<_Range>) && (indirectly_unary_invocable<_Fun, std::projected)())), _Proj> >) constexpr std::ranges::for_each_result, _Fun> std::ranges::__for_each_fn::operator()(_Range&&, _Fun, _Proj) const’
  195 |       operator()(_Range&& __r, _Fun __f, _Proj __proj = {}) const
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/ranges_algo.h:195:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/ranges_algo.h:195:7: note: constraints not satisfied
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/string_view:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/ranges_base.h: In substitution of ‘template<class _Range, class _Proj, class _Fun>  requires (input_range<_Range>) && (indirectly_unary_invocable<_Fun, std::projected<decltype(std::ranges::__cust_access::__begin((declval<_Container&>)())), _Proj> >) constexpr std::ranges::for_each_result<std::ranges::borrowed_iterator_t<_Range>, _Fun> std::ranges::__for_each_fn::operator()(_Range&&, _Fun, _Proj) const [with _Range = zip<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >::iterator; _Proj = main()::<lambda(const auto:18&)>; _Fun = zip<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >::iterator]’:
main.cpp:135:26:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/ranges_base.h:574:13:   required for the satisfaction of ‘range<_Tp>’ [with _Tp = zip<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >::iterator]
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/ranges_base.h:633:13:   required for the satisfaction of ‘input_range<_Range>’ [with _Range = zip<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >::iterator]
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/ranges_base.h:574:21:   in requirements with ‘_Tp& __t’ [with _Tp = zip<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >::iterator]
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/ranges_base.h:576:22: note: the required expression ‘std::ranges::__cust::begin(__t)’ is invalid
  576 |         ranges::begin(__t);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/ranges_base.h:577:20: note: the required expression ‘std::ranges::__cust::end(__t)’ is invalid
  577 |         ranges::end(__t);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

The codes are following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

namespace detail
{
    template <typename... _Tp>
    bool variadic_or(_Tp&&... args)
    {
        return (... || args);
    }
    
    template <typename... _Tp>
    bool variadic_and(_Tp&&... args)
    {
        return (... && args);
    }
    
    template <typename Tuple, std::size_t... I>
    bool any_equals(Tuple&& t1, Tuple&& t2, std::index_sequence<I...>)
    {
        return variadic_or(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t1)) == std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t2))...);
    }
    
    template <typename Tuple, std::size_t... I>
    bool all_equals(Tuple&& t1, Tuple&& t2, std::index_sequence<I...>)
    {
        return variadic_and(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t1)) == std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t2))...);
    }
    
    template <typename Tuple, std::size_t... I>
    bool all_equals(const Tuple& t1, const Tuple& t2, std::index_sequence<I...>)
    {
        return variadic_and(std::get<I>(t1) == std::get<I>(t2)...);
    }
}

template <typename... T>
class zip
{
public:
    struct iterator
    {
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;   
        using value_type = std::tuple<std::iter_value_t<std::ranges::iterator_t<T>>...>;
        using reference = std::tuple<std::iter_reference_t<std::ranges::iterator_t<T>>...>;
        using difference_type = std::tuple<std::iter_difference_t<std::ranges::iterator_t<T>>...>;
        using pointer = std::tuple<typename std::iterator_traits<std::ranges::iterator_t<T>>::pointer...>;
        
        reference operator*()
        {
            return std::apply(
                []<typename... _Tp>(_Tp&&... e) { return std::forward_as_tuple(*std::forward<_Tp>(e)...); }, _data);
        }
        
        iterator& operator++()
        {
            std::apply(
                [this]<typename... _Tp>(_Tp&&... e) { this->_data = make_tuple(++std::forward<_Tp>(e)...); }, this->_data);
            return *this;
        }
        
        auto operator!= (const iterator& iter) const
        {
            return !detail::any_equals(_data, iter._data, std::index_sequence_for<T...>{});
        }
        
        std::tuple<std::ranges::iterator_t<T>...> _data;
    };
    
    zip(T&... args) : data(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<T>(args)...)) {}
    
    auto begin()
    {
        return iterator{std::apply(
            []<typename... _Tp>(_Tp&&... e) { return std::make_tuple(std::begin(std::forward<_Tp>(e))...); }, data)
        };
    }
    
    auto end()
    {
        return iterator{std::apply(
            []<typename... _Tp>(_Tp&&... e) { return std::make_tuple(std::end(std::forward<_Tp>(e))...); }, data)
        };
    }

private: 
    std::tuple<T&...> data;
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto v = vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    auto s = vector<string>{"s0", "s1", "s2"};
    auto d = vector<double>{1.2, 1.3, 3.4};
    
    auto zipped = zip(v, s, d);

    auto test_result = detail::all_equals(*(++zipped.begin()), {v[1], s[1], d[1]}, index_sequence_for<int, double>{});

    if (test_result) { cout << "true" << endl; }
    else { cout << "false" << endl; }
    
    for (auto [x, y, z] : zip(v, s, d))
    {
        cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << endl;
    }
    
    std::transform(zipped.begin(), zipped.end(), zipped.begin(), [](const auto& val) { 
        auto [x, y, z] = val; 
        return std::make_tuple(x+1, y+"_", z+10.0);
    });
    
    std::for_each(zipped.begin(), zipped.end(), [](const auto& val) {
        auto [x, y, z] = val;
        cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << endl;
    });
    
//    std::ranges::for_each(zipped.begin(), zipped.end(), [](const auto& val) {
//        auto [x, y, z] = val;
//        cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << endl;
//    }); // compile error
               
    
    return 0;
}
```

I investigated 'std::ranges::__cust' but couldn't find any relevant information.

Comment: Ah, it's weird that someone closes this question, but they're effectively not the same. I intentionally give an answer, but well just a comment.

Comment: Concept is more friendly than techniques before so that you may trace where the problem is. You can see that `weakly_incrementable<_Iter>` is not satisfied, used by unsatisfied `input_or_output_iterator<_Iter>`, and by `input_iterator<_Iter>`, because of not satisfing `__is_signed_integer_like<iter_difference_t<_Iter>>`. That means, your `difference_type` is not "signed integer like" because it's a tuple! So you may refer to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/weakly_incrementable) and finally know what concept "signed integer like" is and make your `difference_type` so.

Comment: In cppreference, I just go on the same path: `for_each` -> `input_iterator` -> `input_or_output_iterator` -> `weakly_incremental`, and finally find `signed integer like`, so it's not something from nowhere.